# Prestashop - Bankwire file difference

Tags: php, module, smarty, hook, prestashop-1.6

Is anyone can explain what is the difference between

**payment_return.tpl**(path ../bankwire/views/templates/hook/payment_return.tpl)

and

**payment_execution.tpl** (path ../bankwire/views/templates/front/payment_execution.tpl ) ?

Why in **payment_execution.tpl** I can see CART/ORDER variables(such as country name, order weight and other) in **payment_return.tpl** I сan't?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These templates work with different "environment":

1. **payment_execution.tpl** assigned in **/modules/bankwire/controllers/front/payment.php** and have access to all template variables assigned in core files.
2. **payment_return.tpl** appears in [hook](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Managing+Hooks) and have access to limited list of variables. In file **/modules/bankwire/bankwire.php** method **hookPaymentReturn($params)** you may see it, there you have access to *$params* array and can assign to template any additional variables that you need.

Comment: Thanks Sergii, you really helps me with my prestashop question. It's second question you showed me the right way for solve. Now I'm not sure with hookPaymentReturn($params), but I try to fire it out.

Comment: Interesting thing I've found. All variable that could contain product weight of order/cart (such as $this->context->cart->getTotalWeight(), $params['total_weight'] or $total_weight) = 0 in payment_return.tpl Can you help me to understand how can I get product weight in payment_return.tpl ? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can help me with my next question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32629999/show-params-arrayitem

Comment: on payment return step cart is already cleaned and order created, use `$params['objOrder']->getTotalWeight()`

Comment: It's great! Thanks again. If you want you can answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32629999/show-params-arrayitem to get check for right answer.

Comment: I see you are good in Prestashop so I have an proposal. Can you write your contact info(e-mail, skype etc.) we could talk about payment for solving my next questions, because I have it more. Or you can write to my e-mail theitoriginal@gmail.com Thanks.