# Show $params array('{item}' =>…)

Tags: php, arrays, oop, smarty, prestashop-1.6

Need some help. Have this code in `PaymentModule.php` in Prestashop:

```
$params = array(
    '{voucher_amount}' => Tools::displayPrice($voucher->reduction_amount, $this->context->currency, false),
    '{voucher_num}' => $voucher->code,
    '{firstname}' => $this->context->customer->firstname,
    '{lastname}' => $this->context->customer->lastname,
    '{id_order}' => $order->reference,
    '{order_name}' => $order->getUniqReference()
);
```

I use `$params['firstname']` for showing customer `firstname` and get nothing. I insert `$params['firstname']` in `/modules/bankwire/bankwire.php`

Please tell me where I make a mistake?

Thanks

Comment: Remove the `{}` from the array keys, i.e. `$params = array( 'firstname' => ...,)`.

Comment: Kenney : Why are you certain the keys are wrong? The question is tagged with `smarty` and `prestashop-1.6`, so it could very well be a template thingy and removing the curly braces might break it.

Comment: Thanks for edit my question. Sorry, I'm new here and don't understand formatting well

Comment: where do you define the $params array and where do you want to use the entry? either the value is genuine empty, because there was no firstname entered, or there is some kind of transition involved, for example is there mechanism in place that binds the $param elements to a view template?

Answer (score 1):

In your array you have a `{firstname}` key, but no `firstname` key.

If you want to get value, you should use: `$params['{firstname}']`

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this way - $params['{firstname}'] and nothing too. Simple string it displays well, but not array item. Can you tell my else solution?

Comment: try: `print_r($params)` and tell us what output do you get

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$params = array(
    'voucher_amount' => Tools::displayPrice($voucher->reduction_amount, $this->context->currency, false),
    'voucher_num' => $voucher->code,
    'firstname' => $this->context->customer->firstname,
    'lastname' => $this->context->customer->lastname,
    'id_order' => $order->reference,
    'order_name' => $order->getUniqReference()
);
```

or in the case that volkerk is right, try

```
$params['{firstname}']
```

Comment: Why are you certain the keys are wrong? The question is tagged with `smarty` and `prestashop-1.6`, so it could very well be a template thingy and removing the curly braces might break it.

Answer (score 0):

there is variables for email template, it's just assoc array, for access use

```
$params['{voucher_amount}']
```